# Swift 2.0 autolayout constraints programmatically

Tags: swift, autolayout

For some reason I'm getting a `terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException` with this code. I'm just trying to make put autolayout constraints on a tabbar view:

```
func addCommentView() {
    let commentView = UIView.loadFromNibNamed("AddCommentView")
    view.addSubview(commentView!)

    let leftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: commentView!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view,
  attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

    let rightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: commentView!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view,
  attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

   let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: commentView!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view,
  attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

   let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: commentView!, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute,
  multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

   commentView!.addConstraints([leftConstraint, rightConstraint, bottomConstraint, heightConstraint])

 }
```

Comment: It looks like you are setting the height of the commentView to 0. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

You should edit:

```
commentView!.addConstraints([leftConstraint, rightConstraint, bottomConstraint, heightConstraint])
```

to:

```
view.addConstraints([leftConstraint, rightConstraint, bottomConstraint, heightConstraint])
```

Crash will go. But what about height constraint?

Comment: Okay yea, I added a height of 50 and changed it to `view.addConstraints...` and added the line `commentView!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`. Now it works beautifully

Comment: @user3904534 congratulation to you :D